# ArgumentCaptor is capturing other classes

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to capture only one class, lets call it X, where X extends A. There are other classes, that also extends A (such as Y and Z).

When I try to capture X, for some reason, it also seems to capture ALL of the other classes that extends A (such as Y and Z).

I have specified my capture like so:

```
ArgumentCaptor<X> xCaptures = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(X.class);
verify(someService, atLeastOnce()).someMethod(xCapture.capture());
```

However, when I try to get all the values, via

```
xCaptures.getAllValues()
```

I can see that it will contain all of the "sibling" classes as well.

It also appears to be the case if I change the captured class from X to Y.

Why is this happening and how can I get past this?

Note: I have tried to filter our the other classes by using `instanceof` (which I shouldn't have to do in the first place), but that will cause a runtime error since it cannot cast one child class to another.

Here is the general structure of said classes:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class X extends A<XProperties> {
  private SomeOtherClass c;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Y extends A<YProperties> {
  private SomeOtherClass c;
}


@Data
public class A<T> implements SomeInterface {
  // some common fields
}
```

Edit: I should note that the `someMethod` takes in any class that extends A,

```
void someMethod(A<?> childClass);
```

and at some point in my flow, this may actually happen, however the capture, in my mind, should still filter them out.

Comment: @Lino ah yes good catch, forgot to change that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.agalera.eu/mockito-argumentcaptor-inheritance/, in order to use Mockito to handle well inheritance in Java classes,  you will need to do something like this (where A = Animal, X = Dog and Y = Cat):

```
     Mockito.verify(animalProcessor, Mockito.times(2)).processAnimal(animalCaptor.capture());

    List<Animal> processedAnimals = animalCaptor.getAllValues();
    Optional<Animal> dogOptional = processedAnimals.stream()
                                    .filter(a -> a instanceof Dog)
                                    .findFirst();
    Assert.assertTrue(dogOptional.isPresent());
```

Comment: ah yes I see what I did wrong...smh...I was using the child class as the class for the argument capture rather than the parent...doing what you posted works! Thanks!